# How can I preload correct number of images based on screen size?

Tags: html, preload, responsive-images, core-web-vitals, web-vitals

I'm working to optimise [Largest Contentful Paint](https://web.dev/lcp/) (LCP), but am having trouble preloading the correct amount of LCP candidate images based on device size.

The problem:

- on small screens, a single image shows in a carousel
- on larger screens, up to four images can show
- I don't have control of the size of said images, meaning any can be a LCP candidate
- loading all four images on small devices is a no go: a waste of bandwidth and a performance hit

The desired solution:

- preload only one image on small screens
- preload all four images on large devices

My first thought was the obvious one, use the `link` els' `media` attribute to decide what to load; however, all resources are downloaded anyway (refs [1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries), [2](http://scottjehl.github.io/CSS-Download-Tests/)).

I'm not a fan of my current best 'solution' for this: using `link`'s `imagesrcset` + `imagesizes` attributes to load the first image regardless, and the latter images as 1px by 1px on small devices.

E.G.

```
<link 
  rel="preload" 
  as="image" 
  href="image1" 
  imagesrcset="image1-small 100w 200h,image1-large 200w 400h" 
  imagesizes="(max-width: 40em) 100vw, 400px"
>

<link 
  rel="preload" 
  as="image" 
  href="image2" 
  imagesrcset="image2-tiny 1w 1h, image2-small 100w 200h, image2-large 200w 400h" 
  imagesizes="(max-width: 40em) 1px, 400px"
>
```

Clearly very hacky. Is there a 'correct' way of doing this? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it transpires using the `media` attribute for `link` el's of the `type="image"` *does* work.

Lesson learned to always test what I read :)

Therefore the following works to solve the issue at hand:

```
<link 
  rel="preload" 
  as="image" 
  href="image1" 
  imagesrcset="image1-small 100w 200h, image1-large 200w 400h" 
  imagesizes="(max-width: 40em) 100vw, 400px"
>

<link 
  rel="preload" 
  as="image" 
  href="image2" 
  imagesrcset="image2-small 100w 200h, image2-large 200w 400h" 
  imagesizes="400px"
  media="(min-width: 40em)"
>
```